# Which conditional statement is faster than the other (width*height*depth == 0) OR (width ==0 || height == 0 || depth == 0)

Tags: c++, return, return-value

When describing 3-dimensional objects in an algorithm where computation speed is important, which of the following conditional expressions is faster?

```
class Box {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;

public:
    bool isNull(){

       return (width*height*depth == 0);
       //OR
       return (width ==0 ||  height == 0 || depth == 0);
    }
};
```

Comment: Measure/examine assembly. There's no one size fits all answer.

Comment: Superficially, the second option looks faster (but, as StoryTeller says, you'd need to do some benchmarking). However, the context is important! If you're going to be using the `w*h*d` value anyway (if the object is *not* null), then you're better off having already done that calculation.

Comment: First of all concentrate on writing code that is simple, clear, understandable, maintainable, and *working*. Then if simple measurement indicates that the result is not "good enough" (which often *is* good enough) or don't match the requirements on your project, then you do some detailed measuring and profiling to find the top *two* bottlenecks in your code. Optimize those two only, and measure again. If it still not fits the requirements profile again, but this time only for the *single* top bottlneck. Continue until requirements fulfilled.

Comment: And overflow aside, I doubt you'll find any difference for this, unless you have a tight loop doing this a few million times.

Comment: Such questions can't really be answered without the actual code in which you use that functions. Performance can differ between CPU architectures, (the performance of multiplication and comparison can vary, branch prediction, …), the compiler (how it does optimizations), the code that is calling the function, … . Due to that you normally write code so that it is safe, readable, and maintainable, and only if you encounter bottlenecks in your application you check where those occourse and if you can optimize there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your compiler, you can check compiled assembly for both of them and compare. You can as well time 2 options. Second one looks much better though. Note that if any of the values will be non-zero, rest will short circuit and will not be executed. Be sure to put the one that has the highest probability of being non-zero to the front. i.e. `(highestProb == 0 || secondHighest == 0 || leastProb == 0)`

Answer (score 8):

The expression used in the return statement

```
return (width*height*depth == 0);
```

is in general just incorrect relative to the expression in the second return statement. Due to the overflow you can get the result equal to 0 but it does not mean that one of the operands is equal to 0.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << 0x10000000u * 0x10000000u  * 10u << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0
```

though neither operand is equal to `0`.

Comment: While I agree that this is a dumb way to be doing things, it *could* be that the three factors are known to be bounded strongly enough that no overflow can occur. But given the question, I doubt it too.

Comment: @gspr Usually it is a source of a bug when you think that the  three factors are known to be bounded but at one wonderful time it occurs that they are not bounded as you thought.